# why my image path is not taken?

Tags: php, image, src

I am getting the image path from database in this foreach

```
foreach($image as $row){ 
  $value = $row['dPath'];
  $imgpath =base_url()."images/".$value;//this is not taken
  $imgpath =  base_url()."images/con_icon.jpg";//this$imgpath is taken

  echo $value;
```

when i give $imgpath as  $imgpath =  base_url()."images/con_icon.jpg"; it is  accepted in

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" and image is displayed
```

But when i give $imgpath as `$imgpath =base_url()."images/".$value;` 
but `echo $value;` results con_icon.jpg
The image is not displayed
what is the problem

**EDIT:**

```
echo $imgpath =base_url()."images"."/".$value;
 echo $img =  base_url()."images/con_icon.jpg";
```

gave me this

```
http://localhost/ssit/images/con_icon.jpg
http://localhost/ssit/images/con_icon.jpg
```

then why cant i get this in my `<img>`

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" name=b1 width=90 height=80 
 border=0 onmouseover=mouseOver() onmouseout=mouseOut()>
```

Comment: Try some simple debugging: `echo $imgpath` for both versions and see what the difference is.

Comment: please use quotes around your attribute values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your `$value` does not contain extra whitespace at the front or end. use

```
$value = trim($value);
```

to [remove whitespace](http://php.net/trim). also `echo` is not the best way to quick-debug variables, use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) instead.

and please make sure to escape your imagepath to prevent XSS

**edit**

you cannot say `<img src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" name=b1 width=90 height=80 
 border=0 onmouseover=mouseOver() onmouseout=mouseOut()>` because you have whitespace at the end of your string. use `<img src="<?php echo trim($imgpath); ?> … />` if you have to use it this way.

apart from that, quote your attributes: `onmouseover="mouseOver"`, don't use parentheses after your event handler names (unless `mouseOver()` returns a function—i don't think you are doing that …). and you should use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) for your imagepath, to lock out all those malicious hackers who want to harm your users

Comment: @udaya: see, there's the extra space at the end. it should be `string(12) "con_icon.jpg"` and not `string(18) "con_icon.jpg[whitespace]"`

Comment: why the downvote⁉⁉?!? the answer is perfectly valid and even addresses the issue perfectly: whitespace in the filename

Comment: @udaya: **DON'T** use echo, use `var_dump`! from your var_dump result it's clearly visible you have erroneous whitespace in your imagepath. use trim to remove them

Comment: @udaya: i think everything is in my answer. write `$value = trim($value)` before you start appending it to your imagepath. you can also write `$value = trim($row['dPath']);` in your foreach loop

Comment: @knittl  when saw the generated source in webdeveloper i got the source as src="http://localhost/ssit/images/con_icon.jpg%3Cbr%20/%3E"
i made the changes like trim($value);

Comment: @udaya, ok, stackoverflow stripped the html tag at the end. you should enclose code output in `backticks` even in comments. you have a line break `<br />` at the end of your string. i don't know how it went there, but you should probably clean up the value in your db (or where the image path is stored)

Comment: wow There vis a break in database itself i cleared that and it works now .....Really great effort yaar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$value` is not coming empty:

```
var_dump($value);
```

Also, you may try this instead:

```
$imgpath = get_bloginfo('template_url') . "/images/" . $value;
```

Comment: @udaya: use the `trim` before value function as suggested by knittl

Comment: there's a linebreak tag at the end `<br />`, not whitespace. stackoverflow won't display it in comments, unless it's enclosed in backticks. his string is `con_icon.jpg<br />`